# How to integrate $e^{\ln(1+x)}?$ Please help me out with this question.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $e^{\ln(1+x)}$ i.e. $\int\,e^{\ln(1+x)}\,dx$. I know how to integrate $e^{\ln(1+x)}$. It's very easy to integrate. $e^{\ln(1+x)}$ can be written as $(1+x)^{\ln(e)}$ i.e. finally we have to integrate $(1+x)$ i.e. $\int\,(1+x)\,dx$ which is very easy to integrate and the result will be $x+(x²/2\,)+C$; where $C$ is integral constant. But my question is that $e^{\ln(1+x)}$ can be written as $(1+x)$ only when $x>-1$. But if $x<-1$ then $e^{\ln(1+x)}$ will not be equal to $(1+x)$. Then how will I integrate $e^{\ln(1+x)}$? Please help me out.

Comment: If $x \le -1$, then the function is not defined (unless you want to deal with complex numbers). You can just specify that the domain of the indefinite integral $x + \frac{x^2}{2} + C$ is $x > -1$.

Comment: But in case of indefinite integration why I have to always consider the possible values of x? For e.g. in this question why I have to always consider $x$$>$$-$1? Can you give me the actual reason for this@TheoBendit?

Comment: As an aside, please learn the proper use of $ and {} for typesetting; I made numerous corrections so others could read the original question.

Comment: Following on what @AlgTop1854 (who was editing at the same time I was) said: put the dollar signs around the entire mathematical expression, not around individual symbols or superscripts; that will help.

Comment: As for the reason why you have to pay attention to $x>-1$, I think that you said this in your question: because $\mathrm e^{\ln(1+x)}$ only reduces to $1+x$ if $x>-1$. In the real-number system, $\ln u$ is defined only when $u>0$; otherwise, it's undefined and no expression with it can reduce to anything. (But in the complex-number system, $\ln u$ can be defined as long as $u\ne0$, and then $\mathrm{e}^{\ln(x+1)}$ reduces to $1+x$ whenever $x\ne-1$.)

Comment: It is just $x+1$ for all $x$ as seen by the [complex plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=complex+plot+exp%28ln%28a%2Bb+i%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a hard question. It comes down to terminology and definitions.

Let's assume we are talking about reasonable real valued functions and Riemann integration.

It's hard to say always because treatments can vary by author, but generally speaking a function is *integrable* if its integral exists on a finite interval $[a,b]$ that is within the domain of the function. When $a$ or $b$ is allowed to approach $\pm\infty$ or a point not in the domain of the function that leads to improper integrals but let's ignore that.

To *evaluate* integrals, in many cases you can anti-differentiate then evaluate the antiderivative at $a$ and $b$. This is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, linking integration to differentiation.

In your example, you really mean "How can I anti-differentiate $e^{\ln(1+x)}$?"

You can only anti-differentiate a function where is it defined, and this function is defined for $x>-1$ only.  It is the same as $x+1$ on this domain only. Therefore the anti-derivative is as noted above on this domain only. Everyone seems to agree on that.

But for $x\leq -1$, the function is simply undefined because $\ln$ of $0$ or a negative number is undefined, so you cannot anti-differentiate this function for these $x$-values nor can you integrate it on any interval that overlaps with this set.

This is in the context of *real-valued functions* - I just noticed a comment above referred to complex numbers and WolframAlpha.

Comment: After writing this I noticed your (OP) question about "indefinite integration" and why you always have to consider the possible values of $x$.  If you don't, it's just an "algebraic exercise" with symbols has no real meaning and can lead to nonsense. You can start with $x=y$ and get to $1=0$ by ignoring what the values can really be.

Answer (score -3):

By definition of the function $\ln x$, $e^{\ln(x+1)}=x+1$, so $\int e^{\ln(x+1)}\, dx = \int x+1 \, dx = \frac12 x^2+x+C$

Comment: Note that OP is already aware that $e^{\ln(1+x)} = x+1$ for $x > -1$. The question is what happens for $x \le -1$ (which may make sense or not).

Comment: @MartinR it depends on how you define the function $\ln(x)$